# Does brackets extension have a git plugins?

Tags: git

I am using Brackets open source code editor for my project ,,,, every time I complete my work I have to remove the code in diff files and then push it to git which is very tedious one ,, sometime may have chances to miss one or other file ,, so I want to want Does brackets extension have a git plugins? by which I can directly push the code in git as soon I finishes my code?

Comment: This one is most popular git extension for Brackets https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-git

Answer (score 0):

You can try and see if the [`zaggino/brackets-git`](https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-git) extension is able to manage files correctly.
It does provide Git integration for Brackets.

See its [`CHANGELOG.md`](https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-git/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for a complete list of features.